# Time a piece of java code in production.

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, logging, production

I need to time/performance check a piece of code, in production.

The code has java stack. It most probably has log4j integrated. It interacts with a JMS, sends some request on it and pick some response from it. I need to prove that from the user event i.e. click on the front end to the point where it goes and waits for JMS, it is relatively fast. I need to prove (know) that most of the time that it takes, in the round trip is because it is waiting for some message from the JMS.

I am currently looking at http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html. However, I would like to poll the group for suggestions. A few restrictions that I need to work with are:

1. I need something that can be run on production. It needs to be something that I can switch on and off relatively easily.
2. It needs to be something that can not be too heavy memory / CPU usage wise.
3. It needs to be something that I can put into the existing code base with least amount of change in the existing code.

So, does anyone have any suggestions apart from http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html?

Answer (score 1):

[Aspects](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and JVM system arguments (for enabling disabling but requires a restart) or JMX if you need real time on/off.